# Reader is in incorrect state - Sitecore Local instance

Tags: sitecore-client

Currently running into an error with a local instance of Sitecore 8.2.

[image]

```
Reader is in incorrect state
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: Reader is in incorrect state

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Exception: Reader is in incorrect state]
   Sitecore.Xml.Patch.XmlReaderSource..ctor(XmlReader reader, String sourceName) +123
   Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigPatcher.GetXmlElement(XmlReader reader, String sourceName) +45
   Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigPatcher.ApplyPatch(TextReader patch, String sourceName) +120
   Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigPatcher.ApplyPatch(String filename) +92
   Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigReader.LoadAutoIncludeFiles(ConfigPatcher patcher, String folder) +177
```

I have tried taking a look at some of my patch files and everything is the same as another local instance I have running.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/452/error-when-loading-config-reader-in-incorrect-state

Comment: I have seen this. This wasnt the fix. Still unsure what the problem was.